# How can I install a previous Android Support library (version 8)

Tags: android, adt

I have just installed the latest ADT Tools for Eclipse, so I'm right now at v20.0.

This release introduced a new Project wizard, and in one of the last steps it says that it requires the Android Support Library Version 8.
Ok, but in my SDK Manager it tells me I have Android Support Library version 9 installed.

How can I get this  working, is there a way to install the older Android Support Library version 8?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OK, just as I posted my question , I did found a [workaround](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=34169&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars&start=100).

> It seems like the ADT is looking for the Support Libraries in the
>   wrong folder...
>   The folder the libraries are in is:
>   (1) \extras\android\compatibility but ADT looks for them in:
>   (2) \extras\android\support
>   So you have to create the
>   folder (2) and copy all files that are in folder (1) to it.

Answer (score 5):

Above answer is basically correct. But simply copying did not work for me. What worked for me is to:

1. Open SDK Manager
2. Check "Android Support Library"
3. Click "Delete 1 Package"
4. Then check "Android SDK Library" again and
5. Click "Install 1 Package"

This removed the Support Library from extras\android\compatibility and installed it again under extras\android\support